Safe to Carry a Card Containing my Seed Phrase and the Wallet in an International Flight?
As the question says. I have the seed phrase (collection of 24 words like theatre, soldier etc.) written on the card supplied by the manufacturer and the wallet itself.
As I am relocating, it is necessary to carry them with me. But in the process (with all those high tech airport scanners and cameras), what's the safest feasible way? I am actually more concerned about the card than the wallet itself.
If I put it with my locked check-in luggage (under protective layers of clothing and other items), as it will go through different cameras at origin and destination, can any of them pick up the words written on the card (with simple ball point pens)? I am not really a security-tech guy, so I may be paranoid? But is there a possibility?
I am more scared of carrying them (card+wallet) in person as hand luggage, as the security might call for a secondary check.
Assuming you have to carry both of them in the flight, how would you do it, feasibly, and inconspicuously, without drawing attention?
I don't currently have a lot of fund in the wallet, but I intent to continue to use it and keep more. So if it is compromised in the transit I may be screwed years down the line.
